How to pull an image from Azure Container Registry in CircleCI?
I would like to pull a custom image from our private Azure Container Registry in CircleCI. I am aware of the CircleCI Azure ACR Orb, but it seems to only specify how to build and deploy images to the Azure Container Registry. I also know there is a GitHub Action (podman-login) that does the equivalent of what I need.
How can I include a workflow step in my CircleCI configuration file (/.circleci/config.yml) that will authenticate and allow me to pull an image from our Azure Container Registry?

Do these help? https://circleci.com/docs/deploy-to-azure-container-registry/ and https://microsoft.github.io/PartsUnlimitedMRPmicro/hols/circleci.html

@helpinghand unfortunately, those do not help. Thank you though!

It appears the answer was more simple than I anticipated. After configuring the two environment variables (ACR_USERNAME and ACR_PASSWORD) in CircleCI under "contexts", the following did the trick:
  my-service:
    working_directory: /opt/app
    docker:
    ...
      - image: <my-org>.azurecr.io/my/docker/image:<version>-<tag>
        auth:
          username: ${ACR_USERNAME}
          password: ${ACR_PASSWORD}

